# How to make wide form into small group

Tags: forms, input-fields

I'm new on this company and they assigned me to redesign existing web app UI. First is the basic info page. Also they are going more on material design.

[image: This is the current UI]

[image: I group related elements and put it into a sidebar to have a small chunk of fields]

This is the new design.
Let me know if I'm going on the right direction. This form creates new firm

Thanks guys :) any suggestion or comment is really appreciated. By the way how about making this form like onboarding? I will divide each sections.

Comment: Hi marx, this question is likely to get closed for several reasons. Questions on this site need to about a specific UX problem, and need to be answerable in an objective way. This isn't a site for design review, which is the way you've phrased the question. "Let me know if I'm going on the right direction." Answers to that will be primarily opinion based and only of any real value to you. What is the specific UX problem you're asking about here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the solution. I tried my best to arrange the data. One thing I want to suggest you that in your first image you have arrange 3 fields in 1 row. So it looks very messy so always try to keep maximum 2 field. I also tried to arrange 3 fields in each row but again its not looking clean. So keep this.

And in first image you have many number of tab menu compare to second image. So in the case of dynamic menu,it will be good approach to display tabbed menu in left or right side so you will have no problem in the future if menu will be added.

In my screen I have display RED asterisk to display mandatory field and I kept blank space purposefully because there you can show the constrains to enter the data.

[image]

Hope you will like this solution. 
Have a good day !

Here is the example screen.